# Does sudo crontab -e on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 work

Tags: cron

I'm running  3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Its the desktop version not the server version

I needed to create some cron jobs
I `sudo vi dothis.sh` and I put `#!/bin/bash` in the file 
I then `sudo crontab -e` 
I added

```
3 * * * * /root/dothis.sh
```

I'm not sure cron is working If I run the script file manually it does what is in the file 
I modified `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`  and uncommented

```
cron.*                          /var/log/cron.log
```

I restarted cron with `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`

I finally have a `/var/log/cron` and I see some stuff in there but I don't see my `dothis.sh` running every 3 minutes

I think it ran dothis.sh a few times but not every 3 minutes

Am I using the correct approach or has cron changed  - HELP

Answer (score 4):

`3 * * * * /root/dothis.sh` does not run a script every three minutes, it runs a script on the third minutes of every hour (00:03, 01:03, ...). To run a script every three minutes, the syntax is:

```
*/3 * * * * /root/dothis.sh
```

Comment: Hmmm I used http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html to help me with the syntax BUT I guess I still got it wrong

While tring to fix my (maybe perceived) cron problem  I issued sudo crontab /etc/crontab and it seems that my /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root file was changed with what is .in /etc/crontab  Did I mess cron up?

Comment: @ICapatosta There's no punctuation in that comment and I can't make any sense of it. Please edit your current question or ask a new question if this problem is solved.

Comment: I issued the command `sudo crontab /etc/crontab` Now the file in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root is very different than what it used to be 
Did I mess something up

Comment: @ICapatosta If you look `man 1 crontab`, you'll see that if you specify a filename, it will be installed as the user's cron. So when you did `crontab /etc/crontab`, root's cron was replaced with the content of `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: OK so I will read that as no I did not mess something up

Comment: I guess I can `sudo crontab e` and remove everthing that I put in

Comment: am I correct in assuming that the stuff in `/etc/crontab` is already being executed globally

Comment: I am a noob so I will make mistakes and ask stupid questions sorry

Comment: @ICapatosta yes, the commands in `/etc/crontab` is already being executed.

Comment: And *be careful*, the syntax of `/etc/crontab` is **different** from the user crontabs --- there is an additional user field which is not there on the user files --- and mixing them will wreak havoc. (@muru to keep him in the conversation)